# Python array loop not looping/validator issues

Tags: python, arrays, validation, user-input

I'm not exactly sure what I did, but when testing my code it either crashes immediately or gets stuck in a loop. If the first input is a value error (string) and the next is a number it loops as long as the pattern is kept. But if first user entry is int then program crashes. Please any help would be appreciated.

```
def main():
    courseArray = []
    keepGoing = "y"
    while keepGoing == "y":
        courseArray = getValidateCourseScore()
        total = getTotal(courseArray)
        average = total/len(courseArray)
        print('The lowest score is: ', min(courseArray))
        print('The highest score is: ', max(courseArray))
        print('the average is: ', average)
        keepGoing = validateRunAgain(input(input("Do you want to run this program again? (Y/n)")))


def getValidateCourseScore():
    courseArray = []
    counter = 1
    while counter < 6:
        try:
            courseArray.append(int(input("Enter the number of points received for course: ")))
            valScore(courseArray)
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid score between 0-100")
            courseArray.append(int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 100: ")))
    counter += 1
    return courseArray


def valScore(courseArray):
    score = int(courseArray)
    if score < 0:
        print("Please enter a valid score between 0-100")
        courseArray.append(int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 100: ")))
    elif score > 100:
        print("Please enter a valid score between 0-100")
        courseArray.append(int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 100: ")))
    else:
        return courseArray

def validateRunAgain(userInput):
    if userInput == "n" or userInput == "N":
        print("Thanks for using my program")
        return "n"
    elif userInput == "y" or userInput == "Y":
        return "y"
    else:
        print("Please enter y or n")
        validateRunAgain(input("Do you want to run this program again? (Y/n)"))
        return getValidateCourseScore()

def getTotal(valueList):
    total = 0
    for num in valueList:
        total += num
    return total

main()
```

Comment: well, first things first you are calling `int(courseArray)` in `valScore`. This gives rise to error `TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'`

Comment: The recursion in `validateRunAgain` makes no sense.  It should be a loop.  But you're ignoring the return value from the recursive call, so the recursion serves absolutely no purpose.  Then you're calling `getValidateCourseScore`.  Delete all that garbage.  Put it in a loop, and if anything *other* than `Y/y/N/n` is entered, loop and ask again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many inputs from the user, so I have cut down on them and changed it.

Here are the sections of your code which I have changed :

Here `valScore()` I presume validates the input score so, I also gave the index of element to be validated. If it is not valid we remove it from the array and raise ValueError, since it raises error our `counter` is not updated.

```
keepGoing = validateRunAgain()

def getValidateCourseScore():
    courseArray = []
    counter = 1
    while counter < 6:
        try:
            courseArray.append(int(input("Enter the number of points received for course: ")))
            valScore(courseArray, counter - 1)
            counter += 1
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid score between 0-100")
            continue
    return courseArray

def valScore(courseArray, counter):
    score = courseArray[counter]
    if score < 0 or score > 100:
        courseArray.pop()
        raise ValueError

def validateRunAgain():
    while True:
        userInput = input("Do you want to run this program again? (Y/n)")
        if userInput == 'y' or userInput == 'Y':
            return 'y'
        elif userInput == 'n' or userInput == 'N':
            print('thank you for using my program')
            return 'n'
        else:
             print('Enter Y or N')
```